# looking for specific Design Pattern in C++ that solve this problem

Tags: c++, algorithm, design-patterns, data-structures

I am looking for ***specific Design Pattern in C++ that solve*** this problem.

I want to design a Storyboard. Our version of the Storyboard
contains arbitrary many notes (imagine it like putting sticky notes on a board).
Every note has a title, a text and a set of tags. E.g.
- title: "Test Traceplayer"
- text: "Implement a unit test for the class Traceplayer of the spark core framework."
- tags: {"unit test", "traceplayer", "testing", "spark core"}

Our Storyboard should enable us to search for notes by title, text and tags.
E.g.:
  searchByTitle( "Test  Traceplayer" )
  searchByTag({"testing", "unit test"})
  searchByText("Implement a unit test for the class Traceplayer of the spark core framework.")
For the sake of simplicity we don't want to do any similiarity or prefix matching when
searching for a title, tag or text. Only an exact match should give results.

I have number of solution that solve this problem O(1) search complexity But can any one suggest any "Design Pattern" that solve this problem.

Solve that issue with three STL map and get constant time search complexity

Looking for a specific Design Pattern that solves this problem.

I have solved this problem using 3 STL Map and solution get O(1) search complexity

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

#define INPUT 8 

class Note {
public:
    string Tital;
    string Text;
    vector<string> vec;
    Note(){
        Tital = "\0";
        Text = "\0";
    }
};

class storyBoard{
public:
    void AddNote(string Tital,string Text,vector<string> vec );
    void RemoveByTital(string &tital);
    void PrintStoredData();
    Note* searchByTitle(string titleSearch);

    Note* searchByText(string text_);
    vector<Note*> searchByTag(string titleSearch);

    void printSlip(Note *tm);
    storyBoard(){}
private:

    std::map<string,Note *> TitalMap;
    std::map<string,Note *> TextMap;
    std::map<string,std::vector<Note *> > TagsMap;
};


Note* storyBoard::searchByTitle(string titleSearch){
    auto it_v = TitalMap.find(titleSearch);
    if (it_v != TitalMap.end()){
        cout<< "Tital search result is below:-"<<endl;
        return it_v->second;
    } else {
        cout <<"data "<<titleSearch << "  Not found"<<endl;
        return NULL;
    }
}

Note* storyBoard::searchByText(string titleSearch){
    auto it_v = TextMap.find(titleSearch);
    if (it_v != TextMap.end()){
        cout<< "Text search result is below:-"<<endl;
        return it_v->second;
    } else {
        cout <<"data "<<titleSearch << "  Not found"<<endl;
        return NULL;
    }
}

vector<Note*> storyBoard::searchByTag(string tagSearch){
    auto it_v = TagsMap.find(tagSearch);
    if (it_v != TagsMap.end()){
        cout<< "Tag search result is below:-"<<endl;
        return it_v->second;
    } else {
        cout <<"data "<<tagSearch << "  Not found"<<endl;
        vector<Note*> del;
        return del;
    }
}


void storyBoard::AddNote(string Tital, string Text, vector<string> v){
   Note *note = new Note;
   note->Tital = Tital;
   note->Text = Text;
   note->vec = v;

   TitalMap[note->Tital] = note;
   TextMap[note->Text] = note;

   for (auto it = note->vec.begin(); it != note->vec.end(); ++it){
       //check that is tags already 
       auto it_v = TagsMap.find(*it);
       if (it_v != TagsMap.end()){
           it_v->second. push_back(note);
       } else {
           vector<Note *> &v = TagsMap[*it];
           v.push_back(note);
       }
    }   
}

void storyBoard::printSlip(Note *tm){
    cout << "Tital=" << tm->Tital <<endl 
        << "Text=" <<  tm->Text <<endl
        << "Tags = ";
    for (auto it = tm->vec.begin(); it != tm->vec.end(); ++it){
        cout<< *it<<"\t";
    }    
    cout<<endl<<endl;
}

void storyBoard::PrintStoredData(){
    for(auto tm : TitalMap){
        printSlip(tm.second);
    }
    cout<<endl; 
}

void feed_data_for_testing(storyBoard &Sb);
void TestCase(storyBoard &Sb);

int main() {
    storyBoard Sb;
    feed_data_for_testing(Sb);

    Sb.PrintStoredData(); /*Print all contain data */
    cout<<"************* From Here start searching ************"<<endl;
    TestCase(Sb);
    return 0;
}

void TestCase(storyBoard &Sb){    
    Note* obj = Sb.searchByTitle("Tital-3");
    if(obj != NULL){
        Sb.printSlip(obj);
    }

    obj = Sb.searchByText("Text-4");
    if(obj != NULL){
        Sb.printSlip(obj);
    }

    vector<Note *> vec = Sb.searchByTag("tag-3");
    if(vec.size() !=0){
        for (auto it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); ++it){
            //cout<<(*it)->Tital << "\t";
            Sb.printSlip(*it);
        } 
    }   
}

void feed_data_for_testing(storyBoard &Sb){
    vector<string> tags ;
    int count =INPUT;
    for(int i =1;i<=count;i++){
        string tital = "Tital-" + std::to_string(i);
        string text = "Text-" + std::to_string(i);
        tags.clear();
        for(int j =1;j<=i;j++){
            string tag_ = "tag-" +  std::to_string(j);
            tags.push_back(tag_);
        }
        Sb.AddNote(tital,text,tags);
    }
}
```

I am looking for a design pattern that solves this issue.

Comment: *get O(1) search complexity* -- Why not use `std::unordered_map` instead of `std::map`?

Comment: "I have number of solution that solve this problem O(1) search complexity " - I doubt it, but if you have, you can't get much better.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I am looking for Design pattern that solve this issue?

Comment: Why looking for a design pattern? Don't be a pattern programmer. Do it the other way around. Look for a **solution** to your problem. It may look like a common pattern, if so you're lucky since it may be easier to communicate with other programmer. But don't force a pattern that resemble your problem.

Comment: @NeilButterworth I am already mark this ques is as assignment.basically i want to solve this issue with DESIGN PATTERN

Comment: @AshutoshPandey This to me looks more like a data-structures problem, not a design-pattern issue.

Comment: This is Interview ques, I give the number of the solution but interviewer looking for a specific design pattern that solves this issue that the reason I ask you which design pattern solve this problem.

Comment: Taking a quick look at your `storyBoard` definition, I'd honestly say you have a pretty good approach, assuming all the `map`s to `note` pointers are functioning like search indices. I could offer some advice but it would be minor points about style and efficiency. Is your current approach not efficient enough? Is it too hard to use? Does it have bugs? I'm not sure what your problem with this design is.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie i am also same view that quesbelong from data structure

Comment: @AshutoshPandey -- Why not go through the famous patterns (there aren't that many of them) and see which one "fits"?

Comment: Seems like a [boost multiIndex](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html) fits your description quite well.

Comment: @alterigel I am simple write that code, I know need some fine tuning and error handling, but currently I am not focused on that ..currently, think about what is the best data structure and design pattern that give the best solution.

Comment: Small detail: `std::map` has O(log(n)) search complexity, not O(1). Did you mean `std::unordered_map`?

Comment: @AshutoshPandey every design has its trade offs. Please be specific: what about your approach isn't good enough? What do you want to improve? You don't need to think of everything in terms of abstract design patterns.

Comment: @alterigel agree I use unorder_map instead of map

Comment: @alterigel I reject from the interview so I think that approach is not enough

Comment: @AshutoshPandey we have no way of knowing why you why your interview was unsuccessful. What feedback did you get?

Comment: @alterigel He want solution of this problem using some Some Design patter or High level of abstraction of data

Comment: @AshutoshPandey 1. Your supposed `O(1)` is most likely `O(log(n))` binary search. 2. You should change you title because right now it tells absolutely nothing what your problem is about so users you want will not go here. The same goes for those searching for solution will not find this. 3. You should retag slightly to include `spark core framework` if you are using it.

Comment: @AshutoshPandey -- If you look at your `SearchByTitle`, `SearchByText`, and `SearchByTag` the code is basically the same, thus you have code duplication.  How would you get rid of the duplication (does "template" ring a bell)?  Maybe that is what the interviewer is looking for, and not necessarily an "exact" answer.  You not being aware of the code duplication may be the reason why you were rejected.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie might cause this reason to reject me. Can help me how to use a template in the above code (Get data from the map)  as you point out. Due to the different type of data return by map cause I am not able to apply templates here.

Comment: @AshutoshPandey *Due to the different type of data return by map* -- Are you aware you could have added the return type as a template argument?  Isn't "different data types" the problem that templates are made to solve?  Or change your function to return iterators and let the client get the `second`?  This is what the interviewer is probably looking for, and you easily just gave up thinking there was no way to accomplish this (when there certainly is a way).

Answer (score 0):

I update your code at the following point:-

1. convert the class into singleton so that data maintain a single map for each type
2. change **map** to unorder_map

> ```
> #define INPUT 8 
> using namespace std;
>
> /*use class to store single slip data*/
> class Note {
> public:
>     string Tital;
>     string Text;
>     vector<string> vec;
>     Note(){ //constructor to initialize data zero
>         Tital = "\0";
>         Text = "\0";
>     }
> };
> /*create a singalton pattern class so that create only one data storage*/
> class storyBoard{
> public:
>     static storyBoard* getInstance(){
>         storyBoard* Instance= instance.load();
>         if ( !Instance ){
>             std::lock_guard<std::mutex> myLock(lock);
>             Instance= instance.load();
>             if( !Instance ){
>               Instance= new storyBoard();
>               instance.store(Instance);
>             }
>         }   
>         return Instance;
>     }
>
>     void AddNote(string Tital,string Text,vector<string> vec );
>     void RemoveByTital(string &tital);
>     void PrintStoredData();
>     Note* searchByTitle(string titleSearch);
>
>     Note* searchByText(string text_);
>     vector<Note*> searchByTag(string titleSearch);
>
>     void printSlip(Note *tm);
> private:
>     storyBoard()= default;
>     ~storyBoard()= default;
>     storyBoard(const storyBoard&)= delete;
>     storyBoard& operator=(const storyBoard&)= delete;
>
>     static std::atomic<storyBoard*> instance;
>     static std::mutex lock;
>     std::unordered_map<string,Note *> TitalMap;
>     std::unordered_map<string,Note *> TextMap;
>     std::unordered_map<string,std::vector<Note *> > TagsMap;
> };
>
>
> std::atomic<storyBoard*> storyBoard::instance;
> std::mutex storyBoard::lock;
>
> Note* storyBoard::searchByTitle(string titleSearch){
>     auto it_v = TitalMap.find(titleSearch);
>     if (it_v != TitalMap.end()){
>         cout<< "Tital search result is below:-"<<endl;
>         return it_v->second;
>     } else {
>         cout <<"data "<<titleSearch << "  Not found"<<endl;
>         return NULL;
>     }
> }
>
> Note* storyBoard::searchByText(string titleSearch){
>     auto it_v = TextMap.find(titleSearch);
>     if (it_v != TextMap.end()){
>         cout<< "Text search result is below:-"<<endl;
>         return it_v->second;
>     } else {
>         cout <<"data "<<titleSearch << "  Not found"<<endl;
>         return NULL;
>     }
> }
>
> vector<Note*> storyBoard::searchByTag(string tagSearch){
>     auto it_v = TagsMap.find(tagSearch);
>     if (it_v != TagsMap.end()){
>         cout<< "Tag search result is below:-"<<endl;
>         return it_v->second;
>     } else {
>         cout <<"data "<<tagSearch << "  Not found"<<endl;
>         vector<Note*> del;
>         return del;
>     }
> }
>
>
> void storyBoard::AddNote(string Tital, string Text, vector<string> v){
>    Note *note = new Note;
>    note->Tital = Tital;
>    note->Text = Text;
>    note->vec = v;
>
>    TitalMap[note->Tital] = note;
>    TextMap[note->Text] = note;
>
>    for (auto it = note->vec.begin(); it != note->vec.end(); ++it){
>        //check that is tags already 
>        auto it_v = TagsMap.find(*it);
>        if (it_v != TagsMap.end()){
>            it_v->second. push_back(note);
>        } else {
>            vector<Note *> &v = TagsMap[*it];
>            v.push_back(note);
>        }
>     }   
> }
>
> void storyBoard::printSlip(Note *tm){
>     cout << "Tital=" << tm->Tital <<endl 
>         << "Text=" <<  tm->Text <<endl
>         << "Tags = ";
>     for (auto it = tm->vec.begin(); it != tm->vec.end(); ++it){
>         cout<< *it<<"\t";
>     }    
>     cout<<endl<<endl;
> }
>
> void storyBoard::PrintStoredData(){
>     for(auto tm : TitalMap){
>         printSlip(tm.second);
>     }
>     cout<<endl; 
> }
> /**temporary function only use for testing*/
> void TestCase(){    
>     storyBoard *Sb = storyBoard::getInstance();
>     Note* obj = Sb->searchByTitle("Tital-3");
>     if(obj != NULL){
>         Sb->printSlip(obj);
>     }
>
>     obj = Sb->searchByText("Text-4");
>     if(obj != NULL){
>         Sb->printSlip(obj);
>     }
>
>     vector<Note *> vec = Sb->searchByTag("tag-3");
>     if(vec.size() !=0){
>         for (auto it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); ++it){
>             //cout<<(*it)->Tital << "\t";
>             Sb->printSlip(*it);
>         } 
>     }   
> }
> /**temporary function only use for testing*/
> void feed_data_for_testing(){
>     storyBoard *Sb = storyBoard::getInstance();
>     vector<string> tags ;
>     int count =INPUT;
>     for(int i =1;i<=count;i++){
>         string tital = "Tital-" + std::to_string(i);
>         string text = "Text-" + std::to_string(i);
>         tags.clear();
>         for(int j =1;j<=i;j++){
>             string tag_ = "tag-" +  std::to_string(j);
>             tags.push_back(tag_);
>         }
>         Sb->AddNote(tital,text,tags);
>     }
> }
>
> int main() {
>     storyBoard *Sb = storyBoard::getInstance();
>     feed_data_for_testing();
>
>     Sb->PrintStoredData(); /*Print all contain data */
>     cout<<"************* From Here start searching ************"<<endl;
>     TestCase();
>     return 0;
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I think the term *design pattern* was mistakenly used by your interviewer in place of the term *idiom*.

A major issue with your code (and could be the cause of rejection) is **memory handling** using classical c++ idioms:

- use of smart pointers to manage the lifetime of your notes
- [rule of 3 (or 5)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) to handle copy/assignment(/move) of your `StoryBoard` object

Note that using smart pointers is only one way of managing the memory. You could as well use other idioms:

- arena of notes and referencing notes from the arena inside your hashmaps
- ...

Once this issue is solved you have minor issues:

- returning pointers instead of references, the `StoryBoard` is the owner of the memory, you should not return a pointer that a caller could inadvertently free.
- no const accessors (returning const references)
- repetitive code that could be factored

If I am not mistaken in interpreting what the interviewer said, this question should be moved to codereview.stackexhange.com